# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Vue/laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, laravel-8

i have a problem with my vue component when i'm trying to update a product it returns an error put method is not supported... But it should be supported.

my EditProduct.vue

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" v-model="product.name">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Description:</label>
     <textarea name="description" cols="20" rows="5" v-model="product.description"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
     <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

my submit method: (i tried patch/put insted of axios.post but it still doesnt work)

```
    submitForm(){
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('_method', 'PUT');
        data.append('id', this.product.id);
        data.append('name', this.product.name);
        data.append('description', this.product.description);
        axios.post('edit', data)
        .then( (response) => {
            console.log("success");
        })
    }
```

my api route:

```
Route::put('/edit', [ProductController::class, 'update']);
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just as I posted the question I realized the url for axios is wrong it should've been

/api/edit

it works now :)